# Getting no of products in all categories and parent categories contains a keyword

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch all the categories and their count (no of products in that category) of those products where keyword matches. The query I tried doesn't give me the correct result.
Also I want the parent categories till level 1 and their count as well.

e.g. I am trying with keyword watch, then category "watches" should be there with some count. Also the parent category "accessories" with the sum of its descendant categories count.

my table structures are:

**tblProducts:** There are 5 categories of a product, fldCategoryId1, fldCategoryId2, fldCategoryId3, fldCategoryId4 and fldCategoryId5. fldProductStatus should be 'A'

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------+
| Field                       | Type              |
+-----------------------------+-------------------+
| fldUniqueId                 | bigint(20)        |
| fldCategoryId1              | bigint(20)        |
| fldCategoryId2              | bigint(20)        |
| fldCategoryId3              | bigint(20)        |
| fldCategoryId4              | bigint(20)        |
| fldCategoryId5              | bigint(20)        |
| fldProductStatus            | enum('A','P','D') |
| fldForSearch                | longtext          |
+-----------------------------+-------------------+
```

**tblCategory:**

```
+------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Field                        | Type                  |
+------------------------------+-----------------------+
| fldCategoryId                | bigint(20)            |
| fldCategoryName              | varchar(128)          |
| fldCategoryParent            | int(11)               |
| fldCategoryLevel             | enum('0','1','2','3') |
| fldCategoryActive            | enum('Y','N')         |
+------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**Search Query:**

```
SELECT count( c.fldCategoryId ) AS cnt, c.fldCategoryLevel, c.fldCategoryParent, c.fldCategoryId, c.fldCategoryName, p.fldForSearch, c.fldCategoryParent
FROM tblCategory c, tblProducts p
WHERE (
    c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId1
    OR c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId2
    OR c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId3
    OR c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId4
    OR c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId5
)
AND p.fldProductStatus = 'A'
AND (
    MATCH ( p.fldForSearch )
    AGAINST (
        '+(watches watch)'
        IN BOOLEAN MODE
    )
)
GROUP BY c.fldCategoryId
```

**Note:** The table is in the **InnoDB** engine and have FULLTEXT search index on *'fldForSearch'* column.

**EDIT:** sample data can be found in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06d04b/4)

Comment: Can you live with the [`rollup`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) output? The sums would be listed below/above each group, not as part of each row (so you might have to do some preparations before displaying it). You might consider doing the summation in your app (e.g. use the treenode class in php). If you add the table structures and some example data as pasteable code (the create and insert statements), as well as the expected output, you make it easier to test the answer. Can you change tblCategory? It's not the best tree model for databases (but works here)

Comment: After fighting this battle with millions of products and hundreds of categories in SQL server, I can tell you that the queries just get more complicated and no amount of hardware and fancy coding will make it fast.  You may want to consider something like SOLR or ElasticSearch

Comment: Thank Jen R, Elastic Search is the next stage for this. For now I want to solve this with scripting (PHP) and queries.

Comment: Is it possible, that a product is directly assigned to a categorie X and to an ancestor of X? E.g.: fldCategoryId1 is X and fldCategoryId2 is parent of X.

Comment: Paul - yes, its possible

Comment: ankitr, can you post the script for the table creation to the question proper?  I am having difficulty accessing the sqlfiddle.  Please note that we are supposed to write Questions so that they are still informative in months or even years in order to improve the quality of StackExchange's researchable knowledge base.  Links to sqlfiddles are very handy in the short term, but they have a limited lifespan.  As such, it is optimal to present your sample table script and your code in the Question as well as an sqlfiddle.  I look forward to tackling this question.

Comment: ankitr, Is `fldCategoryParent` meant to be a foreign key field used to refer to the `fldCategoryId` of the parent `Category` record?  If so, then why isn't it the same data type as `fldCategoryId`?  And what value will it hold when it is an ultimate parent (i.e. has no parent itself)?  And should `c.fldCategoryParent` be repeated in your supplied query?

Comment: What value will `fldCategoryId1`, etc. have if there is no category in that field for that `Product`?

Comment: Re : `Also I want the parent categories till level 1 and their count as well` - If  `Accessories` has the children `Heavy` and `Light` and `Heavy` has the children `Red`, `White` and `Blue` and their `count`s are `20`, `10`, `15`, `1`, `2` and `3` respectively, are you asking us to display a field with `Aceesories` and another field with an associated number?  Should that number be `5` (the count of `Accessories`' child nodes), `6` (same count but including `Accessories`), `31` (the total count for the children of `Accessories`) or `51` (total count including `Accessories`)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> Also I want the parent categories till level 1 and their count as well.

But the following query will show you a count for each category (including those with 0 found products), and a general rollup:

```
SELECT 
    c.fldCategoryId, 
    c.fldCategoryLevel, 
    c.fldCategoryName, 
    COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM tblCategory c
    LEFT JOIN tblProducts p ON
            (c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId1
        OR  c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId2
        OR  c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId3
        OR  c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId4
        OR  c.fldCategoryId = p.fldCategoryId5)
        AND p.fldProductStatus = 'A'
        AND MATCH ( p.fldForSearch )
            AGAINST (
                '+(watches watch)'
                IN BOOLEAN MODE
            )
GROUP BY 
    c.fldCategoryId
    c.fldCategoryLevel,  
    c.fldCategoryName
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Notes:

- you cannot select `p.fldForSearch` if you expect a count of all the products in the category. `fldForSearch` is on a per product basis, it defeats the grouping purpose
- I left joined with products so it returns the categories with 0 products matching your keywords. If you don't want this  to happen just remove the `LEFT` keyword
- I haven't checked the `MATCH` condition I assume it's correct.

Comment: Category level is 0,1,2,3. if keyword found at level 3 then level 2, level1 and level0 parent categories should be there with there count.

Comment: Query took 143 seconds to execute and did not give the required result.

Comment: how about you provide a sqlfiddle with some samples?

Answer (score 1):

Start by not splaying an array (`fldCategoryId...`) across columns.  Instead, add a new table.

Once you have done that, the queries change, such as getting rid of `OR` clauses.

Hopefully, any further issues will fall into place.

Comment: its good idea but changing structure at this stage is not quite possible. There are millions of records and too many scripts are dependent on this structure.

Answer (score 1):

Since your category tree has a fixed height (4 levels), you can create a [transitive closure table](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/transitive-closure-table/info) on the fly with

```
SELECT c1.fldCategoryId AS descendantId, c.fldCategoryId AS ancestorId
FROM tblcategory c1
LEFT JOIN tblcategory c2 ON c2.fldCategoryId = c1.fldCategoryParent
LEFT JOIN tblcategory c3 ON c3.fldCategoryId = c2.fldCategoryParent
JOIN tblcategory c ON c.fldCategoryId IN (
    c1.fldCategoryId,
    c1.fldCategoryParent,
    c2.fldCategoryParent,
    c3.fldCategoryParent
)
```

The result will look like

```
| descendantId | ancestorId |
|--------------|------------|
|            1 |          1 |
|            2 |          1 |
|            2 |          2 |
|          ... |        ... |
|            5 |          1 |
|            5 |          2 |
|            5 |          5 |
|          ... |        ... |
```

You can now use it in a subquery (derived table) to join it with products using `descendantId` and with categories using `ancestorId`. That means that a product from category X will be indirectly associated with all ancestors of X (as well as with X). For example: Category 5 is a child of 2 - and 2 is a child of 1. So all products from category 5 must be counted for categories 5, 2 and 1.

Final query:

```
SELECT c.*, coalesce(sub.cnt, 0) as cnt
FROM tblCategory c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tc.ancestorId, COUNT(DISTINCT p.fldUniqueId) AS cnt
    FROM tblProducts p
    JOIN (
        SELECT c1.fldCategoryId AS descendantId, c.fldCategoryId AS ancestorId
        FROM tblcategory c1
        LEFT JOIN tblcategory c2 ON c2.fldCategoryId = c1.fldCategoryParent
        LEFT JOIN tblcategory c3 ON c3.fldCategoryId = c2.fldCategoryParent
        JOIN tblcategory c ON c.fldCategoryId IN (
            c1.fldCategoryId,
            c1.fldCategoryParent,
            c2.fldCategoryParent,
            c3.fldCategoryParent
        )
    ) tc ON tc.descendantId IN (
        p.fldCategoryId1,
        p.fldCategoryId2,
        p.fldCategoryId3,
        p.fldCategoryId4,
        p.fldCategoryId5
    )
    WHERE p.fldProductStatus = 'A'
        AND MATCH ( p.fldForSearch )
            AGAINST ( '+(watches watch)' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
    GROUP BY tc.ancestorId
) sub ON c.fldCategoryId = sub.ancestorId
```

Result for your sample data (without level, since it seems to be wrong anyway):

```
| fldCategoryId | fldCategoryName | fldCategoryParent | fldCategoryActive | cnt |
|---------------|-----------------|-------------------|-------------------|-----|
|             1 |             Men |                 0 |                 Y |   5 |
|             2 |     Accessories |                 1 |                 Y |   5 |
|             3 |       Men Watch |                 1 |                 Y |   3 |
|             5 |           Watch |                 2 |                 Y |   5 |
|             6 |           Clock |                 2 |                 Y |   3 |
|             7 |     Wrist watch |                 1 |                 Y |   2 |
|             8 |           Watch |                 2 |                 Y |   4 |
|             9 |          watch2 |                 3 |                 Y |   2 |
|            10 |        fastrack |                 8 |                 Y |   3 |
|            11 |           swish |                 8 |                 Y |   2 |
|            12 |         digital |                 5 |                 Y |   2 |
|            13 |          analog |                 5 |                 Y |   2 |
|            14 |            dual |                 5 |                 Y |   1 |
```

Demos:

- [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06d04b/15)
- [rextester](http://rextester.com/CSIRQB59189)

Note that the outer (left joined) subquery is logically not necessary. But from my experience MySQL doesn't perform well without it.

There are still ways for performance optimisation. One is to store the transitive closure table in an indexed temporary table. You can also persist it in a regular table, if categories do rarely change. You can also manage it with triggers.

Comment: Paul your approach having parent categories as well but still count is not correct.

Comment: @ankitr Can you tell me which count is wrong, and what it should be?